# WebHDFS REST API and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, webhdfs

I have a Hadoop cluster and I want to manipulate data from a Spring Boot microservice: Create folders / Put Data/ Read Data/ Delete Data...

There is an API: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

but I don't know how I can use it in a spring boot project.

I found this example, but with HBASE: [Spring Boot REST with Hadoop HBASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261564/spring-boot-rest-with-hadoop-hbase)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: "Spring Boot" doesn't matter. It's just Java libraries you need to use

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use WebHDFS. Add `hadoop-client` Java dependency and use the Filesystem class to interact directly with HDFS via Namenode RPC

Otherwise, read the REST API documentation for WebHDFS and use WebClient class to construct HTTP requests